# java use of super() in inheritance

Tags: java, super

I'm making Construct classes that use Inheritance and I'm having a hard time with using the `super()`. I have the `InterestCalculator class` that is the parent of the `CompoundInterest Class`. I'm trying to use the `super()` in the Compound Interest class.Your constructor InterestCalculator takes **3 paramenters (Principal Amount, InterestRate, and term)**
I need to invoke the `CompoundInterest` which takes `4 parameters` and I need to pass the **3 (PrincipalAmount, InterestRate, and Term)** and the `4th parameter` is specific to the `CompoundInterest`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InterestCalculator
{

  protected double principalAmount;
  protected double interestRate;
  protected int term;

  public InterestCalculator(double principalAmount, double interestRate,          int term)
  {
     this.principalAmount = principalAmount;
     this.interestRate= interestRate;
     this.term = term;
  }   
  public double getPrincipal()
  {
      return principalAmount;
  }       
  public  double getInterestRate()
  {
     return interestRate;
  }
  public  double getTerm()
  {
     return term;
  }
  public double calcInterest()
  {
     return -1;
  }
  protected double convertTermToYears()
  {
    return (this.term / 12.0);
  }
  protected double convertInterestRate()
  {
    return (this.interestRate / 100.0);
  }
}
public class CompoundInterest extends InterestCalculator
{
  protected int compoundMultiplier = 0;       

  super.CompoundInterest(double compoundMultiplier);
  {
    super.principalAmount = principalAmount;
    super.interestRate = interestRate;
    super.term = term;
    this.compoundMultiplier = (int) compoundMultiplier; 
  }
  public double calcInterest()
  {
    double calcInterest = (super.principalAmount *Math.pow((1.0+((super.convertInterestRate())/this.compoundMultiplier)),(this.compoundMultiplier *(super.convertTermToYears()))))- super.principalAmount;              
    return calcInterest;    
  }
}
```

Comment: You're just making it up. Why not learn the language?

Comment: It seems you are writing a constructor without knowing java. Please read it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a constructor in your derived class that accepts all the arguments it is going to need:

```
public class CompoundInterest extends InterestCalculator {
    protected int compoundMultiplier;

    /**
     * Constructor for CompoundInterest.
     */
    public CompoundInterest(double principalAmount, double interestRate, int term,
        int compoundMultiplier)
    {
        super(principalAmount, interestRate, term);
        this.compoundMultiplier = compoundMultiplier;
    }

    . . . // rest of class
}
```

Note that inside the constructor, `super(...)` invokes the superclass constructor. You don't do this by putting `super.` in front of your constructor name.
By calling `super(...)` (which, if present, must be the first line of the subclass constructor), the matching base class constructor will be invoked and will use the arguments to set the appropriate fields. There's no need to try doing it again from the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

The `CompoundInterest` class has several mistakes.

1 - You must called a superclasst constructor. Since `InterestCalculator` has only one constructor `(double, double, int)`, you need to call it right on the beginning of the `CompoundInterest` constructor.

2 - You are using `super` in the wrong way on `super.CompoundInterest`. `super` is used to access a method from the superclass. You must rename it to `CompoundInterest`.

3 - As mentioned on the firs item, you need to call a constructor from the superclass. You do it like this: `super(principalAmount, interestRate);`. Remember: it must be the first call of the constructor.

4 - You are not passing to the `CompountInterest` any of the three parameters it is expecting. You should consider to put these arameters in the `CompoundInterest` as well.

If you apply these changes, your code will loke like this:

```
CompoundInterest(double compoundMultiplier, double principalAmount, double interestRate, int term); {
    super(principalAmount, interestRate, term);
    this.compoundMultiplier = (int) compoundMultiplier; 
}
```